# Non-linear assumed form in Galerkin method

Tags: reference-request, numerical-methods, finite-element-method, galerkin-methods

The wikipedia article on [Method of mean weighted residuals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_mean_weighted_residuals) has a section on choice of test functions, in particular it says about Galerkin method:

> The Galerkin method, which uses the basis functions themselves as test functions or in the more general case of a **nonlinear assumed form** (where the nonlinearity is in the degrees of freedom) of the solution the Galerkin method uses the test functions: 
>   $$ w_{i}={\frac {\partial u}{\partial a_{i}}}$$

I'm really interested in the "**nonlinear assumed form**". I would like to know what is known about Galerking when we assume nonlinear form of the trial function.

Unfortunately the wiki article gives only one reference to a book which I was unable to get hold of. Can anyone direct me to any other source where I can read more about this topic?

Comment: Could it be that 'nonlinear assumed form' means that Galerkin function depend nonlinear on degree of freedom $a_i$? This wiki page is indeed very confusing.

Comment: I think that is exactly it, but I would like to know more about the consequences of this nonlinearity. All texts talk about Galerkin method where you assume that the unknown function is a linear combination of fixed basis functions.